# Set the counter value on Timer.Interval

Tags: c#, timer, system.timers.timer

I have a timer which I am using to execute an event in the method. I need to run it every 5 minutes but need to change the counter value when the timer ticks at t 10 minutes but then again reset the counter.

So, when the timer execution is past 5,15 or 25 minutes I need to set counter value to 1. While on 10, 20 or 30 minutes interval I need to set it to 2. So, in short the default counter value will be always 2 while when the execution time is a multiple of 10 & then again reset to default again.

How should I do that on System.Timers?

Here's what I have so far:

using System.Timers;

```
namespace Demo
{
    public class SampleWorker
    {
        private Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        private bool _timerInUse = false;
        private double _timerFrequency = 300000;
        private int _counter = 1;


        public void Main()
        {
            StartTimer();
        }

        private async void StartTimer()
        {
            try
            {
                timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.TriggerEvent);
                timer.Interval = _timerFrequency; //5 mins
                timer.Enabled = true;
                // when timer runs with units as 5 set _counter to 2 else keep 1
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log exception
            }

        }

        private async void TriggerEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_timerInUse == false)
            {
                _timerInUse = true;
                try
                {
                    Foo(_counter);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   //log exception

                }
                _timerInUse = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to make the question more clear. When you write _"need to change the counter value when the interval is at 5 minutes"_, it is not clear what you mean, because the code above never modifies the `Interval` property at all. The `Interval` will always be 2 minutes (120000 milliseconds), and so saying something happens _"when the interval is at 5 minutes"_ is meaningless. Possibly you mean simply that this occurs when the _elapsed_ time is a multiple of 5, but even then it's not clear what the exact behavior of the counter should be. The post should include a proper ...

Comment: ... [mcve], along with a detailed explanation of what exactly that code does, what exactly you want it to do instead, and what exactly you can't figure out. Note that since the `System.Timers.Timer` class has nothing to do with Winforms, your code example also should have nothing to do with Winforms. A regular console program should suffice to present your question properly.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the comments. Timer's interval will always stay 2 minutes its the timer's execution time that needs to change the counter when it runs for 5 mins change the counter to 2 but on the 6th minute again reset it to 1. I'll edit the language & will try to make it more clear.

Comment: If the timer interval is always 2 minutes, how do you expect to do _anything_ on the 5 minute mark? Shouldn't you use a timer interval of 1 minute, and then monitor the elapsed time to determine what logical operations you want to perform? For example, the statement above that _"when the timer ticks at t 5 minutes"_ is meaningless, because the timer will _never_ tick at 5 minutes. With an interval of 2 minutes, it can only tick at 2, 4, 6, 8, etc. minutes.

Comment: ok how about the timer uses 5 min interval & at multiples of 10 it will set the counter to 2? Like 5,15,25 sets 1 & 0,10,20 does it 2. The reason I want to do this is because I want to avoid using two different timers.

Comment: The example in your previous comment requires nothing more than alternating the values (well, not counting the possibility of a late-delivered timer tick). I.e. if the value is 1, set it to 2, otherwise set it to 1. That seems somewhat different from the problem you are presenting in your question. Nonetheless, the question has not been improved in the way I suggested. All I can say is that your interval should be 1 minute (greatest common divisor of 2 and 5), and then on each interval reported by the timer, look at the _elapsed_ time (e.g. `Stopwatch`) and use that to determine what to do.